# Configure Sublime Text on OS X to show partial directory path in title bar

Tags: macos, sublimetext

Is there a way to display a partial directory path in the title bar?

Currently the title bar displays `mypath/otherdir/project/file.txt`. But I'd like it to be `/project/file.txt`

Is there a setting that I'm missing that says 'show only the last x-pathitems' or something like that?

To set the full path you can use `Sublime Text > Preferences > Settings`
and add the line `"show_full_path": true,`

Comment: Check [this thread on Sublime Forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/relative-path-in-title-bar/8009/3).

Comment: Too bad it doesn't exist yet.. Thanks for the link @the4kman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Sublime forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/relative-path-in-title-bar/8009/3), as the4kman mentioned.

Basically: It's not a standard Sublime Text setting. It's counter intuitive to the 'working with projects' philosophy, seeing as you use the current working directory as reference point for displaying the directory path.